# Mysql entry contains check

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to check if any row contains "9123456" and I have row with value "+9123456" which is a match and another case is where my value is "9123456" and i need to check for "+9123456" and here is where i am stuck.

I need to check both ways, if possible under a single query. Is this possible ?

Comment: MYSQL support the use of `AND`.

Comment: Can you provide the table schema with sample data as better example

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this, what have tried so far?

Comment: What's the data type of that column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `replace` function to strip the `+` from the column (presuming the `+` is the only one in that column).

```
SELECT number FROM phonenumber WHERE replace(number, '+', '') = 9123456
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/750609/2

or a regular expression:

```
SELECT number FROM phonenumber WHERE number regexp '^\\+?9123456$'
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/750609/5

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be casting both the column and your input number to `UNSIGNED INTEGER`.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    phonenumber
WHERE CAST(number AS UNSIGNED) = CAST('+9123456' AS UNSIGNED);
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d1a4d/1/0)

**More:**

You can add `0` to the input number before matching with your `column number`.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM phoneNumber WHERE number = '9123456'+0;
```

*Adding zero(`0`) to a `varchar` will convert it to a number if the `varchar` contains a valid number represented as string. Otherwise result is `0`*

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d1a4d/2/0)